# twitter bootstrap collpage with data-toggle issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, custom-data-attribute

I've a field which when checked toggle a text field.
[See demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nyKD9/)

When user selects *Yes*, a text field is shown. When user selects *No* text field hides. This is fine.

Problem is, click on *Yes*, text field shows up now if again clicked on *Yes* text field hides. It should be visible until user selects *No* only.

How can I do that ? I can easily do this with jQuery, no issues. But since bootstrap gives ability to do this with markup only I want to go for that.

Here's markup -

```
<div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="inputPreviousSurname">Previous Surname</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="radio" name="previousSurname" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"> Yes
            </label>
            <label class="checkbox inline">
                <input type="radio" name="previousSurname" checked data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"> No
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div id="demo" class="collapse in">  <input   type="text" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know of to do this is through jQuery (but using the bootstrap collapse function)

Otherwise bootstrap will just treat it as a toggle.

HTML

```
 <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPreviousSurname">Previous Surname</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input id="show" type="radio" name="previousSurname"> Yes
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox inline">
            <input id="hide" type="radio" name="previousSurname" checked="" > No
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="controls">
        <div id="demo" class="collapse">  <input   type="text" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#show').click(function(){
      $('#demo').collapse('show');
  });
  $('#hide').click(function(){
      $('#demo').collapse('hide');
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2E2En/3/

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. I didn't want to do this with own script but I guess there's no other way. Thanks for posting. :)